# Django initial form values from db query in views

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to set initial values in form for editing within views. For example i want to edit book that is allready stored in database setting initial values from database query. Is it possible in django ?
For instance:

views.py:

```
from .models import Book
from .forms import BookForm

def edit_book(request,book_id):
    query_book=Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    Book_form_to_edit =BookForm(initial=query_book)
    context={
    'book_form':Book_form_to_edit,
    }
    return render(request,'edit_book.html',context)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yess, it is possible try referring the code below. I have edited your code so you will grab some idea on it.

```
from .models import Book
from .forms import BookForm

def edit_book(request,book_id):
    query_book=Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    Book_form_to_edit =BookForm(request.POST, instance=query_book)

    if Book_form_to_edit.is_valid():
      Book_form_to_edit.save()

    context={
      'book_form':Book_form_to_edit,
    }
    return render(request,'edit_book.html',context)
```

and in url.py make sure to get the book_id

```
path('<int:book_id>/Edit/', views.edit_view, name='edit')
```

Comment: What if it is not request.POST but request.GET ? I was thinking i can use POST to update book data ? Besides i'm getting TypeError  "Exception Value:  

cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence"

Comment: sorry i uploaded the code without finishing it. Check the code once again. The request is POST cause you have the edit and save the form so POST is best way to save item in database

Comment: Perfect man  - it did a trick , just had to modify query to receive single object with 'get'. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad to be of some help.